# Topology induced by equivalent norms

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, equivalent-metrics

Let $X$ be a vector space, equipped with two norms $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ Which are equivalent.

What is the easiest way to prove that these two equivalent norms induce same topology?

Comment: By showing that any open ball under norm 1 contains an open ball under norm 2 and vice versa.

Comment: I don't mean to oversimplify, but the definition I just found of equivalent norms is that they induce the same open sets, in which case this fact is immediate...